# Using videos in img html

Tags: caniuse, html5-img

Referencing this article: https://cloudinary.com/blog/evolution_of_img_gif_without_the_gif

What is the compatibility situation with videos in img in 2020? I don't know what the name of the feature is called to look for in caniuse.

> - Now you can `<img src=".mp4">`s in Safari Technology Preview
> - Early results show mp4s in  tags display 20x faster and decode 7x faster than the GIF equivalent - in addition
>     to being 1/14th the file size!
> - Now we wait for the other browsers to catch-up

Comment: You should quote some of the relevant content from the article in your question, in case the link goes offline. Perhaps quote `In the latest Safari Tech Preview, thanks to some hard work by Jer Noble, we can now use MP4 files in <img> tags.`

Comment: In 2020, keep up on  webm: https://www.webmproject.org/

Comment: @LonnieBest question's about HTML not media formats.

Answer (score 1):

By today (Oct 2022), we still can only use `<img src=".mp4">` on Safari.
If you want to make MP4 files work like GIFs on other browsers, you might wanna use `<video autoplay muted loop>`.

Answer (score 0):

- MP4: `<img src="foo.mp4">` only supported in Safari
- Animated GIF: `<img src="foo.gif">`  supported in all modern browsers
- Animated WebP: `<img src="foo.webp">`  supported in all modern browsers